# Change Button Text on Android

Tags: android, button, timer

I have a simple android app with a button who have the text HELLO.
If i do not push this button after 10 seconds i want the text to be WAIT.
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: in that u have to use timer.... by using timer u can set button text WAIT after 10 Sec.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(changeFunction(), 10*1000);
```

write above in onCreate()

```
private Runnable changeFunction(){ 
      t = new Timer();
      tt = new TimerTask() {              
          public void run() { 
              handler.postDelayed(changeFunction(), 10*1000);
              button.setText("WAIT");
          }          
      };          
    return tt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

check this timer task for 10 seconds ...button.setText("Wait...");

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Timer buttonTimer                   =   new Timer();
final Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    button.setText("WAIT");
}
};

buttonTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
    }
},10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timed handler message.

```
Button b;
boolean notPressed;
b.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(notPressed){
            b.setText("Wait");
        }
    }
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b;
boolean notPressed;
b.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(notPressed){
            b.setText("sexy");
        }
    }
}, 10000);
```