# change the keyboard layout after a button click

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm developping an android app , and i have an `EditText` and a two `RadioButtons` (**A** and **B** ),

what i'm trying to do is :

When `RadioButton` A is checked , i want to change the keyboard layout to display it with the Done button , 
When the `RadioButton` B is checked, i want to change the keyboard layout to display it with the Search Button .

I've tried to change the `IMEOptions` of my `EditText` like this , but it still doesn't work :

NB : the keyboard is already visible, what i want to do is just modify the button **Search** with the button **Done** in each case of the two `radioButtons`

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(btnA.isChecked() ) { 
        txtSearch.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
//      txtSearch.invalidate(); 
    }
    else {
        txtSearch.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
//      txtSearch.invalidate();
    }   
}
```

any ideas about how to do that ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What Android version are you targeting? I'm unable to post a comment sorry (new account), but am currently doing up a testcase to answer your question.

**EDIT:** Ok, I've figured it out. After a bit of googling (see [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15106)) and coding, I found that the imeOptions appear to be cached/tied to the input method. I'm not sure if this is a bug or intentional functionality. To switch the keyboard when the user taps either radio button, first make sure the inputType is set for your EditText (`android:inputType="text"`), then use the following in your `onCreate` method:

```
final RadioGroup btn_group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.btn_group);
final RadioButton btnA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnA);
final RadioButton btnB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnB);

btn_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        final EditText txtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        txtSearch.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        if(btnA.isChecked()) {
            txtSearch.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        } else {
            txtSearch.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
        }

        txtSearch.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }
});
```

Note the nulling out and re-setting of the InputType.

[image]
[image]

Finally, please be aware that many popular keyboard implementations don't give a damn what you set the `imeOptions` to, so don't rely on this functionality in your app. Swype for example;

[image]

In conclusion (see what I did there?), not to be outdone, I've bundled up my test program. You can find it here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/52276321/ChangeKeyboardTest.zip

Comment: thanks aaronsnoswell for your help , i will test your programm now and tell you back if it is working for me :) +1

Comment: Small improvement:

int inputType = txtSearch.getInputType();
txtSearch.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
txtSearch.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
txtSearch.setInputType(inputType);

Comment: This is almost awesome. Problem is that it moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line. Thanks again, Android.

Comment: This works for me and didn't observe issue with moving cursor back to beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Based on standing on the shoulders of giants, here's what I came up with. Thanks to @aaronsnoswell.

```
private void imeSetup(boolean isDoneOk){
    if (isDoneOk!=lastIsDoneOk) {
        int inputType = editText.getInputType();
        int selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        if (isDoneOk)
            editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        else
            editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
        editText.setInputType(inputType);
        editText.setSelection(selectionStart);
        lastIsDoneOk = isDoneOk;
    }
}
```

Without the `lastIsDoneOk` shenanigans I went into an infinite loop. YMMV because I'm calling this from within a `TextWatcher`, so you may not need it. Without keeping track of `selectionStart`, Android brings the cursor back to the start.

Answer (score 0):

try this `RadioGroup`. It will work definitely. OR use link

**https://gist.github.com/475320**

```
// This will get the radiogroup
RadioGroup rGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(r.id.radioGroup1);
// This will get the radiobutton in the radiogroup that is checked
RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)rGroup.findViewById(rGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());


// This overrides the radiogroup onCheckListener
rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rGroup, int checkedId)
    {

    switch(checkedId){
        case R.id.btnA:
            txtSearch.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            break;
        case R.id.btnB:
             txtSearch.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
            break;enter code here
        default:
            break;
    }
       txtSearch.setCloseImeOnDone(true); // close the IME when done is pressed
    }
});
```

Comment: there is no such method setCloseImeOnDone(true);  which level of androdi sdk you have used ? i'm using api level 10

Comment: best example is here check this link at least once...https://gist.github.com/475320

Answer (score 0):

try use class handler to update views dynamically.

from: [Change Button Text on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805606/change-button-text-on-android)

Comment: my code is running on the uiThread, so i don't need to use the handler to update the UI Keyboard