# Android dynamically change keys in soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem with my custom view that contains an edittext and a spinner. I have added a "next"-button using IMEoptions. Depending on the spinner, the edittext keyboard should contain either a "next" or a "done" key.

At the moment I solve this using:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    final Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if (item.equals(getString(STRING1))) {
    edittext.setImeOptions(EditOptions.IME_OPTIONS_NEXT);
    } else if(item.equals(getString(STRING2)){
    edittext.setImeOptions(EditOptions.IME_OPTIONS_ACTION_DONE);
    }
    edittext.setText(edittext.getText());
     //This updates the edittext but is very much an ugly hack. 
     //Is there another way to update this? invalidate() and forceLayout() 
     //does not do the trick
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate solution.

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

As described here:
[change the keyboard layout after a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480105/change-the-keyboard-layout-after-a-button-click)